# log transformation of whole dataframe using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, logarithm

I have a dataframe in python which is made using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', sep="\t")
df1 = df.iloc[:, 3:]
```

now in df1 there are 24 columns. I would like to transform the values to log2 value and make a new dataframe in which there are 24 columns with log value of original dataframe. to do so I used `numpy.log` like the following line:

```
df2 = (numpy.log(df1))
```

this code does not return what I would like to get. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Why isn't it working? SHould be fine

Comment: *"I would like to transform the values to log2 value"*  Try the function [`numpy.log2`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.log2.html).